# How to input String in Java in line by line or like 50 characters per line

Tags: java, string, input, output

So, I am creating a program in which the user has to enter the body(message) of the email. Now when I display that instead of doing it in a proper way the compiler just displays a long line. I have tried using \n but it doesn't work.

```
System.out.println("Enter  message");
Scanner e4 = new Scanner(System.in);
String message  = e4.nextLine();
System.out.println(message);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that just because your email program shows you line breaks doesn't those are really there, it just breaks depending on the window size. So the email would still be just one line of text and that what your program reads. Also adding "\n" into the text doesn't help. That's not a line break, just a slash and an "n" without any meaning.

Comment: @Ezio could u please attach the screenshot of i/p and o/p which u have received.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. You can keep pushing line after line onto an ArrayList until you see a particular end string. In my example it's "end", but equally it could be "</p>" or something else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Scan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter here:");
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(true) {
            String temp = in.nextLine();
            if(temp.equals("end"))
                break;
            input.add(temp);
        }
        for(String s : input) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```